# Upper bound of ${e^{ - \frac{{a{x^2} + b{x^2}}}{2}}}\left[ {C - \frac{{{x^2}d}}{2}} \right]$, $C,a,b,d>0$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, convex-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

I have a function ${e^{ - \frac{{a{x^2} + b{x^2}}}{2}}}\left[ {C - \frac{{{x^2}d}}{2}} \right]$,

Where, $C > \frac{{{x^2}d}}{2}$ and $C,a,b,d > 0$.
I was trying to find the upper bound of the function in the form of ${x^2} \times \left\{ {f\left( {.....} \right)} \right\}$.

I tried but could not extract $x^2$ outside the bracket for upper bound. I dont know if it is impossible or I am missing some inequality relation. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it just $C$? Both factors are decreasing functions of $x^2.$

Comment: Does that mean lower bound is zero?

Comment: Given the constraint $C > \frac{{{x^2}d}}{2},$ yes. The expression is a continuous function of $x^2,$ which therefore tends to zero as $x^2$ tends to $2C/d$; and it is strictly positive, because of that constraint.